# What is the difference between a lemma and a ghost method?

Tags: dafny

What (if any) is the difference between a `lemma` and `ghost method`. I was under the impression that they are both the same but calling a ghost method from a lemma throws the following error `in a hint, calls are allowed only to lemmas`, i.e.

```
ghost method foo ...
lemma bar ..
  ..
  calc {
   {foo ..;} // <--- ERROR!
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lemma is semantically the same as a ghost method. For example, in a location where a method may be called, such as a statement in a block statement within a method, it does not matter whether a lemma is relabled as a ghost method.

However, it appears that in some situations, such as the block of statements in an assert-by statement or a calc statement, Dafny currently insists that a ghost method be specifically called a lemma. And calling it a lemma more clearly communicates its purpose to readers.

I'll enter an Issue for the Dafny developers to ask whether this behavior is desired, but for now just call it a lemma if you are going to use it in calc and similar statements.